# The plane is a disjoint union of sequences converging to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Can $\mathbb{R^2}$ be written as a disjoint union (necessarily uncountable) of  sequences converging to $0$?

Comment: Hint: Can this be done for $\mathbb{R}$?  If so, take a sequence for each point in $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R})$.  Are you assuming the axiom of choice?

Comment: Let $<_0$ be a well-order for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take the first element $a_0$, according to $<_0$. Define the sequence $a_0,a_1,...$ by taking $a_{n+1}$ to be the first element, according to $<_0$, such that $|a_{n+1}|<|a_n|/2$. Such $a_{n+1}$ always exists because the disc $\{z\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ |z|<|a_n|/2\}$ is uncountable and we have only taken out a countable number of elements at every stage. Exclude those elements from the set and repeat to form new sequences. Apply transfinite induction to exhaust the list.

Comment: Yes, of course, and there is a much simpler construction, without any axioms of choice or transfinite induction. But why would anybody need this?

Comment: Ah, yes of course, thank you. I needed this in a more sophisticated context, I am not sure this proof translates. I will post another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any normed space $\mathbb{X}$, let $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\|x\|}.$$ Obviously, $f$ is injective, we have $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{1-\|x\|}$$ if $\|x\|<1.$ Let $$s(x)=(x, f(x), ff(x),fff(x),\ldots).$$ Since we can trace back any member of such a sequence back to the first element (just apply $f^{-1}$ as long as possible, i.e. as long as $\|x\|<1$), they are disjoint for different starting values. Let $\mathbb{X}_0=\{x\in\mathbb{X}:\|x\|\ge1\},$ and $\mathbb{X}_{n+1}=f(\mathbb{X}_n)$. Then, 
$$\mathbb{X}=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{X}_0\cup\{0\}}s(x).$$
That's easy to see, because $\mathbb{X}_n=\{x\in\mathbb{X}:\frac1n>\|x\|\ge\frac1{n+1}\}$ for $n\ge1$, so they are disjoint, and any $x\neq0$ is in some $\mathbb{X}_n$.

Comment: The sequences $s(x)$ and $s(y)$ are distinct for $x\ne y,$  but I assumed that distinct  sequences $(x_n)_n, (y_n)_n$  should be disjoint in the sense that  $\{x_n\}_n\cap \{y_n\}$ is empty.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Those intersections _are_ empty. Otherwise, a common element could be traced back to the same starting value, because $f$ is injective, and there can't be more than one starting value $x$ with $\|x\|\ge1$.

Comment: I misunderstood your construction.  Your set of sequences is $\{s(x):x=0\lor x\in \mathbb X_0\}.$... And we don't even need a well-order of $\mathbb X.$......+1

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let's show how to write $(0,1)$ as a disjoint union of sequences converging to $0$. Every number with continued fraction $[0, a_1,a_2, \ldots, ]$ belongs to the sequence $([0,n, a_2, \ldots])_{n\ge 1}$, and this sequence has limit $0$.

$\bf{Added:}$

Easier to look at it as follows: Do this for every ray in $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus reduce to $(0,\infty)$. Consider the map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ from $(0,\infty)$ to itself. Now reduce to partitioning $(0,\infty)$ into sequences that have limit $\infty$. This is simple, the sequences are $(n+a)_{n\ge 0}$ for $a\in (0,1)$.

Note that this is essentially the same solution as the above, and as the solution of @Professor Vector: